# Prove that limit does not exist using delta-epsilon

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\to1} \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$$
I'm trying to prove that this limit does not exist. Here is my attempt:

Given $L > 0$, we want to prove$$\exists\epsilon>0, \forall\delta, 0<|x-1| < \delta \land |\frac{1}{(x-1)^2} - L| > \epsilon $$
Let $\epsilon = 1$ and fix $L$.

Then
$$|\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}| > L + 1 \implies \frac{1}{x-1} > \sqrt{L+1} $$
$$\implies x-1 \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{L+1}}$$

Let $\delta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{L+1}}$

Is this sufficient as a proof?

Comment: The square root of $(x-1)^2$ is not necessarily $x-1$. According to your argument, $$\left|\frac1{(0.9-1)^2}\right|>48+1,$$ so $$-10=\frac1{0.9-1}>\sqrt{48+1}=7.$$

Comment: @MartinArgerami I don’t think the post is saying that $\left| \frac{1}{(x – 1)^2} \right|$ *is* greater than $L + 1$; instead, it is saying that *if* this inequality holds then the two inequalities after it hold as well. In any case, the definition of limit was wrong to begin with, so I am not sure what any of the subsequent statements are supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1):

As [Mark Viola’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2011461/843797) correctly shows, when you allow infinite limits, this limit is $\infty$. Your continued references to $L$ indicate that you do not allow infinite limits (which [is also acceptable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/420658/843797)), in which case the limit does not exist. But your proof misstates the definition of limit. Below is a valid proof, including the correct definition.

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{(x – 1)^2} = Y
\end{equation}

is equivalent to

\begin{equation}
\forall(\epsilon > 0) \exists(\delta > 0) 0 < |x – 1| < \delta \implies \left| \frac{1}{(x – 1)^2} – Y \right| < \epsilon.
\end{equation}

No such value of $\delta$ exists, though. Per Mark Viola’s answer, we can actually find $\delta$ such that

\begin{align}
0 < |x – 1| < \delta &\implies \frac{1}{(x – 1)^2} > Y + \epsilon\\
&\implies \left| \frac{1}{(x – 1)^2} – Y \right| \not< \epsilon
\end{align}

This is true no matter what $Y$ is, showing that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The limit of interest is $\infty$.  To prove this, we let $\epsilon>0$, however large, be given.  Then, we have for $x\ne 1$

$$\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}>\epsilon$$

whenever, $0<|x-1|<\delta =\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$.  And we are done!

Comment: What happens to the $L$?

Comment: Bob, there is no "$L$" that is relevant.  If $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\infty$, then for any $\epsilon>0$, however large, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|>\epsilon$ whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$.

Comment: OP is clearly using a definition that only allows for finite limits, and apparently such a definition [is generally accepted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/420658/843797).

Comment: When $0 = |x – 1|$, $\frac{1}{(x – 1)^2}$ is undefined. The inequality should be $0 < |x – 1| < \delta$.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score -1):

x approaches 1 as x-1 approaches 0 as (x-1)^2 approaches 0 as 1/(x-1)^2 approaches infinity.

Comment: -1 Extremely confusing and does not answer the question.